# Vagrant NameError: undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, vagrantfile, vagrant-plugin

I had one Vagrantfile on VirtualBox running on my machine (MacBookPro) that was working pretty well. Then I installed another Vagrantfile.

Even though I destroyed them both I still can't get it to load with `vagrant up`

I closed all virtual machines manually and still I get this error...

`$ vagrant up`

```
There was an error loading a Vagrantfile. The file being loaded and the error message are shown below. This is usually caused by a syntax error.    

Path: /Users/actual_username/.vagrant.d/boxes/actual_vagrantfile_name/0.3-centos-actualSNAPSHOT_number/virtualbox/Vagrantfile
Line number: 0
Message: NameError: undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add 
`Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|` wherever you are using the config variable in your vagrantfile.